# How to avoid NullPointerException in Scala while storing query result in variable

Tags: scala, match

Here is a code that requires a change:

```
val activityDate = validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0).toString
```

When we run a job, 'activityDate' might return null as a result of query since there might not be any data in db. In this case we get NullPointerException. I need to update this code to avoid NPE.

I tried to do it in different ways but there is always smth missing. I should probably use Match Expression here but have face some errors while initializing it.

Comment: I provided a very generic answer. It looks like you are using some library to issue a SQL query, I assume to `mysql` given how you tagged the question. If would be useful to know which library you are using, at it might have some built-in way of dealing with nullable columns that leverages the `Option` type without forcing you to roll out your own way of dealing with that.

Comment: Looks like it might be Spark.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to model some kind of data that might or might not be there in Scala is the `Option` type. The `Option` type has two concrete implementations, `Some` for a value which is there and the `None` singleton to represent any absent value. `Option` conveniently has a constructor that wraps a nullable value and turns it into either a `Some(value)` for non-null values and `None` for nulls. You can use it as follows:

```
Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0))
```

You can apply transformations to it using various combinators. If you want to transform the piece of data itself into something more meaningful for your application, `map` is usually a good call. The following applies the logic you had before:

```
val activityDate: Option[String] = 
  Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0)).
    map { activityDate => activityDate.toString }
```

Note that now `activityDate` is an `Option` itself, which means that you have to explicitly handle the case in which the data is not there. You can do so with a match on the concrete type of the option as follows:

```
activityDate match {
  case Some(date) => // `date` is there for sure!
  case None => // handle the `select` returned nothing
}
```

Altenrnatively if you want to apply a default value you can use the `getOrElse` method on the `Option`:

```
val activityDate: String = 
  Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0)).
    map { activityDate => activityDate.toString }.
    getOrElse("No Data")
```

Another possibility to apply a default value on a `None` and a function to the value in a `Some` is using `fold`:

```
val activityDate: String = 
  Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0)).
    fold("No Data")(activityDate => activityDate.toString)
```

As a final note, you can shorten anonymous functions in these cases as follows:

```
val activityDate: String = 
  Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0)).
    fold("No Data")(_.toString)
```

Where `_` is used to refer to the only parameter.

Comment: I think, the `null` comes from `get(0)`, not from `.first` (`activityDate` is a `Row`, with the single column, which is the actual date).

Comment: You are probably right, looks like `first` throws on an empty `DataFrame`. Edited, thanks for reporting! :)

Comment: Here is what I have now:
Option(validation.select("activity_date").first.get(0))
val activityDate match {
case Some(date) =>
case None => "No Data"
}

Does it look correct? And what should I put after => for Some(date)? I need to store result of query into activityDate

Comment: You can use `getOrElse` to get the value from the `Option` or use a default if it's not there. I updated my answer.